# Regex for function calls like A(x=10,y=20,z=56);

Tags: java, regex

Can you tell me how to write a reg-ex for the following type of function call?

```
A(x=10,y=20);
B(x=34); 
C(x=20,y=30,z=40);
```

There can be any upper case letter instead of `A`, `B` or `C`, and `x`/`y`/`z` can be any lower case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A(x=10,y=20,z=67) this type of formula.We can use any upper case letter instead of A and x y z can be any lower case letter –  Chathuranga

Please see the following regex:

```
"([A-Z]\([a-z]=\d+(?:,[a-z]=\d+)*\);)+"

/(
 [A-Z] # An uppercase character
 \(    # A literal "("
 [a-z] # A lowercase character
 =     # A literal "="
 \d+   # Some digits
  (?:,[a-z]=\d+)* # Optional repeat groups
 \);   # Literal character sequence ");"
)+     # One or more
 /x
```

<strike>This answer was completed for the sportsmanship, I started writing it before the question was closed, hence now I have deleted the answer.</strike>

**There is nothing to see here.**